# Overriding the default Route in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcroutehandler

Is there any way to override the default routing(~/home/index) without changing anything RouteConfig.cs, that's upon ctrl+F5, the page has to open the route we want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your project
2. Select Properties
3. Select Web
4. Check Start Url
5. Enter Url you want to open when you press ctrl+f5

[image: How to change default url on project startup]

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't understand. What do you want to open with code? Properties window? By following steps above you change default url when your project starts only in debugging mode. It's useful when you are working on a page and you need to restart project several times. This way you don't need to change url every time you start project.